# How often should we change Coolant Temperature Sensor, and is it life time long?

Tags: nissan, coolant, sensor, temperature, sunny

I drive Nissan Sunny 2010 N16, it has 225000 KM, I am experiencing extra fuel consumption, for 45 Ltr it makes only 350 KM in average (high way/city) driving, one week back I changed the oxygen sensor but no luck, now I am thinking to change the Coolant Temperature Sensor cause it has been for long (5 years, 180000 KM) not changed

Comment: Is there any reason to think it's failed? Engine code for instance?

Comment: no engine code at all

Comment: BTW - Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the sensors on my car have done 200,000km so don't just change them... It is easy to spend a lot of money changing the wrong thing...

You should check for error codes and make sure the service items are good ie is the air filter clean, fuel filter, plugs and you should also check the tire pressures.

Comment: I change them cause I get extra performance enhanced, as a sample the transmission got well and smoothly when I changed the Oxygen Sensor

Comment: air filter clean every oil change till it gets free of dust, spark plugs changed 3 months back, tire pressure as mentioned I check every 15 days, it doesn't show much lose

Comment: @MahmoudHboubati - You're mixing apples and oranges here. Air/oil filters are maintenance items and should be changed regularly. A sensor should last as long as it's going to last ... you don't need to change it in the meantime (ie: there are some exceptions like the O2 [or lambda] sensor). Changing out a temp sensor will not give you any better performance or fuel economy *unless it has failed*.